# Adding a key and value to the data before submit in a React JS Form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, parameter-passing

I'm stuck trying to add an extra element (idEmp and its value) to the data that will be send in the onSubmit event, the values typed in the form are working ok but I need to add this extra Element to store it.

I tried to assign the idEmp value to an input hidden control but it didn't work, so I'm out of ideas, your suggestions will be welcome, this is my source code:

```
import { Box, Button, DateInput, Form, FormField, TextInput } from 'grommet';
import { Clock, Money } from 'grommet-icons';
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function FormLayout({ onSubmit, currentValues }) {
  const defaultValues = {
    ...currentValues,
  };
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(defaultValues);

  const { idEmp }  =  useParams();
  //console.log("idEmp: " + idEmp);

  return (
    <Form
      value={value}
      onChange={(nextValue, { touched }) => {
        console.log('Change', nextValue, touched);
        setValue(nextValue);
      }}
      onReset={() => setValue(defaultValues)}
      onSubmit={(event) => {
        console.log('Submit', event.value, event.touched);
        onSubmit(event.value);
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <p>Employee ID: <b><i>{ idEmp }</i></b>, Full name: { }</p>
      </div>

      <FormField label="Internal ID" name="idMedCert">
        <TextInput name="idMedCert" />
      </FormField>

      <FormField label="Medical Service" name="medicalService">
        <TextInput name="medicalService" />
      </FormField>

      <FormField label="Doctor's Name" name="mdName">
        <TextInput name="mdName" />
      </FormField>

      <FormField label="Days Off" name="daysOffMedCert">
        <TextInput name="daysOffMedCert" />
      </FormField>

      <FormField label="MedCert's Start Date" name="startDateMedCert">
        <DateInput name="startDateMedCert" format="yyyy-mm-dd" />
      </FormField>

      <FormField label="MedCert's End Date" name="endDateMedCert">
        <DateInput name="endDateMedCert" format="yyyy-mm-dd" />
      </FormField>
      
      <FormField label="Date of Register" name="recordedDateMedCert">
        <DateInput name="recordedDateMedCert" format="yyyy-mm-dd" />
      </FormField>      
      
      <Box direction="row" justify="between" margin={{ top: 'medium' }}>
        <Button label="Cancel" />
        <Button type="reset" label="Reset" />
        <Button type="submit" label="Submit" primary />
      </Box>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default FormLayout;
```

Comment: Can you show what is present in the `event.value` object?

Comment: Sure, basically each letter typed is added to the value, just like this:  Object { idMedCert: "18", medicalService: "Odontology" }
 
Object { idMedCert: true, medicalService: true }
FormLayout.js:19

Comment: but idEmp is a param I got from a previous step and I need to add it to the data that will be submitted

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grommet, but to my understanding of how form libraries work (Redux Form, React Final Form) this `values` object will have all the keys and their values for various form fields, correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct, I'm stuck how to add a new key and value (which is idEmp and its value)

Comment: If yes, you can save the value of  idEmp in state using the useState hook, and then assign it to the values object when you need to click submit in the callback function like this: `values.idEmp = {the value from state}`

Comment: You can add keys to objects by directly using the dot syntax like `values.idEmp = value that you are assigning`

Comment: thank you so much Link, this line did the magic: event.value.idEmployee = idEmp;

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my buddy @Link, the next lines solved my problem:

```
  onSubmit={(event) => {
    event.value.idEmployee = idEmp;
    console.log('Submit', event.value, event.touched);
    onSubmit(event.value);
  }}
```